# Is there a way to schedule Photoshop batches

Tags: windows, automation, photoshop

I have a photoshop batch that needs to be run on about 70+ folders, at least once per day.

Right now, we manually open photoshop, load the batch, select an in and out folder, and run it.

I'd like this to happen automatically if possible, as it takes about a minute to do it manually, which is over an hour per day of man-hours.

I've tried googling it, but it's not the easiest thing to google as I'm looking to automate an automated process :).

Right now we're using CS5.5 but will be upgrading to CS6 shortly, running on Windows.

If anyone has any experience or ideas on how to go about doing this, I'd appreciate it.

Aaron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How often do the import/export paths change? Not knowing the nature of the whole process it's difficult to assess how difficult to be. Could you not create a series of droplets for each process (import from a --> process --> put into b, import from a --> process --> put into c etc)
Sounds like you need a script to control the entire process with a UI giving various options at the beginning which would speed things up.

Comment: Hi Ghoul.  Thanks for the response.
I just spoke with the designers, and learned a little more.  Apparently we have a droplet setup for each folder (refers to a specific franchise), and they drag the images over the relative droplet.
They edit the droplet once a month, and change the input/output folder to reference the current month.  (I can fix that myself using a symbolic link to the current month, so that will eliminate that task.)
However, if possible, I'd like to have specific folders monitored, and if files are dropped in that folder, then the droplet or batch runs.

Comment: What you are looking for a windows shell script that will watch the a particular folder and then execute that Photoshop action/script when something is added to the folder.